# How do I write this for-loop in functional style?

Tags: kotlin, for-loop

I have a function with a for-loop:

```
fun List<Int>.customSum(sumFunction: (Int) -> Boolean): Int {
    var sum = 0
    for (item in this) {
        if (sumFunction(item))
            sum += item
    }
    return sum
}
```

I want to know how I can write the above in functional style. I know that I have to use `this.reduce()`, but don't know exactly how to implement it.

Answer (score 2):

```
return filter(sumFunction).sum()
```

Should be self-explanatory.

You can’t use reduce because it doesn’t let you reject the first element.

With fold it would be:

```
return fold(0) { a, b -> 
    if(sumFunction(b)) a + b else a
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I can think if two ways to achieve that:

1. The first one is by using `sumOf {...}`:

.

```
fun List<Int>.customSum(sumFunction: (Int) -> Boolean): Int {
    return sumOf {
        if (sumFunction(it)) it else 0
    }
}
```

2. The second one is by using `filter {...}` then `sum()`:

.

```
fun List<Int>.customSum(sumFunction: (Int) -> Boolean): Int {
    return filter(sumFunction).sum()
}
```

Comment: or shorter: `fun List<Int>.customSum(sumFunction: (Int) -> Boolean) = filter(sumFunction).sum()`

Answer (score 0):

```
return this.reduce { sum, n -> if (sumFunction(n)) sum + n else 0}
```

Comment: This will include the first value in the sum even if it doesn’t pass the condition.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use `reduce` for some reason you can - but you need to add that *0* to the head of the list as your "start state":

```
fun List<Int>.customSum(sumFunction: (Int) -> Boolean): Int {
    val stuff = listOf(0) + this
    return stuff.reduce { a, b -> a + if (sumFunction(b)) b else 0 }
}
```

You have to do that because `reduce` is really there to combine a bunch of items, which is why for the first iteration you get the first two items in the list. You don't get to handle them separately, which is why you need to throw that *0* in there to get past that first step, and get to a point where you can just do your checking on the second parameter and ignore the first one, treating it as an accumulator instead of another item you also need to check.

That behaviour is what `fold` is for - with that function you pass in an initial state (which can be a completely different type from your items, since you're not just smushing them together to create a new value like with `reduce`) and then on each iteration you get that state and an item.

You can handle the item as you like, and then make changes to the accumulator state depending on the result. Which is exactly the behaviour of your `for` loop! `fold` is just a functional way to write one. [Tenfour04's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73926802/13598222) is how you'd do it - it's the right tool for the job here!